# Receiving TypeError while running as python program but working fine on console

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with a 3rd party [python library](http://python-paillier.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which basically allows certain encryption operations. It is working as expected as I test the methods using the console (See code below) and return the values properly.

The OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

```
test@2c215fcff3bf:/# python3

Python 3.5.2
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>>from phe import paillier
>>>public_key, private_key = paillier.generate_paillier_keypair() 
>>>secret_number_list = [3.141592653, 300, -4.6e-12]
>>>encrypted_number_list = [public_key.encrypt(x) for x in secret_number_list]
>>>encrypted_number_list[0]
<phe.paillier.EncryptedNumber object at 0x7ff56b695630>
```

Now when I try to use the same code but wrapped it around RESTful API using Flask. It is gives me error "TypeError: 'EncryptedNumber' object is not callable". I must be doing something wrong but is not apparent what it is.

```
Sample.py
from phe import paillier
from flask import request, url_for
from flask_api import FlaskAPI, status, exceptions

app = FlaskAPI(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def encrypt():

    public_key, private_key = paillier.generate_paillier_keypair()
    secret_number_list = [3.141592653, 300, -4.6e-12]
    encrypted_number_list = [public_key.encrypt(x) for x in     secret_number_list]
    if encrypted_number_list[0] is not None: 
       return "OK"

    return "FAIL"
```

Comment: Which line exactly triggers the exception?

Comment: @AttoAllas Its the line "return encrypted_number_list[0]"

Comment: Ok! Please tell me *exactly* what you want the server to return to the client so I can help you

Comment: please fix the identation @Razi in `encrypt()` function

Comment: The indentation is actually correct but when I pasted the code it does not reflected here correctly.

Comment: @AttoAllas It should just give the phe.paillier.EncryptedNumber object the same way when I call return encrypted_number_list[0] on the console.

Comment: Happens in SO, its our job to make sure that it is right in the question :)

Comment: Give it where? To the client? The server cannot send objects, so you have to serialise them into json or xml if you want to send them

Comment: @AttoAllas To the client. I actually added a check to ensure that the object is not null  "if encrypted_number_list[0] is not None:" and its not. This means  need to covert the object and do the operations and finally return the string (which is what would be the final value) to the client.

Comment: Wait, so is it returning "OK" or encrypted_number_list[0]?

Comment: It is returning" OK".

Comment: What is the error then? You said the error happened on `return encrypted_number_list[0]`, but surely that no longer exists?

Comment: Post the complete traceback when you run it in console @Razi

Comment: @AttoAllas Correct. I think it was bit misleading error since it was really not the case of calling the method but rather issue with the serialization. May be I should either update the question and add the details or simply delete the question and it turns out to be a completely different thing.